# Haskell - variable not in scope error - beginner

Tags: haskell, new-operator

I'm new to haskell and cannot work out what is wrong with my code. 
I keep getting a variable out of scope error.

Here is my code that i load into GHCi using `:load`

```
validLength :: String -> Bool
validLength xs | length xs == 26 = True
               | otherwise = False
```

I then type `validLength aa` which should return false but i'm getting an error.

```
*Main> validLength aa

<interactive>:1:13: error: Variable not in scope: aa :: String
```

Comment: I think you mean `validLength "aa"`.

Comment: You here make use of a variable `aa` which, likely, does not exists. If you want to pass a `String`, you should use `validLength "aa"`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks a lot, my mistake :-)

Comment: Note that operator `==` already returns a boolean. There is no need to check if that is true, and then return `True`/`False` accordingly. You can directly return the result of `==` e.g. `isZero x = x == 0`.

Comment: I.e., `validLength xs = length xs == 26`.

Answer (score 4):

Identifiers are not strings. (This is by no means special to Haskell, it's the same in most other languages.) So, when you give `aa` as the argument, GHC interprets it as *the name of some variable*. But, well, there is no variable with that name, at least not in scope, thus the error.

If you want to pass actually *the string consisting of two `a` characters*, then you should use a string *literal*. A string literal is simply a string in double quotes (again, that's the same way it is in many other programming languages).

```
*Main> validLength "aa"
False
```

Comment: It's really kind of you to provide such a good answer from such a beginner and simple question, thanks for you time. I remember when I had the same type of doubts

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little thing to your code, don't be afraid to return an expression or function that returns a Boolean value:

```
:t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

so,

```
3==4 -> False
length [1,2,3] == 26 -> False
```

So your code could be simply:

```
validLength :: String -> Bool
validLength xs = length xs == 26
```

or:

```
validLength :: String -> Bool
validLength =  (== 26) .  length
```